# How can I with XSLT get count of all preceding elements that have specified attribute name?

Tags: xslt

I have some XML file that contains elements with id attributes. I need to have id values in proper order counting from the root element. So instead of this one:

```
       <body>
            <p id="1">
                <span id="3"/>
            </p>
            <p/>
            <div id="8">
                <p id="2"/>
                <ul>
                    <li/>
                    <li id="9">
                        <span id="12"/>
                    </li>
                    <li/>
                    <li id="13">
                        <span id="7"/>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </body>
```

I would like to have this:

```
        <body>
            <p id="1">
                <span id="2"/>
            </p>
            <p/>
            <div id="3">
                <p id="4"/>
                <ul>
                    <li/>
                    <li id="5">
                        <span id="6"/>
                    </li>
                    <li/>
                    <li id="7">
                        <span id="8"/>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </body>
```

Comment: the use of id attributes beginning with numbers is discouraged and not supported in html4 [read more](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the identity transformation template plus one for the `id` attributes:

```
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="@id">
    <xsl:attribute name="id">
        <xsl:number count="*[@id]" level="any"/>
    </xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>
```

http://xsltransform.net/3NSSEvD